# How to publish a fat JAR to JitPack using shadowJar gradle plugin and not maven publish

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jitpack, shadowjar

It's not immediately intuitive on how to publish a fat JAR to JitPack because the shadow docs don't have a section for JitPack and the JitPack docs don't have a section on fat jars.

All the docs say is that if you include `maven-publish` then they will execute the task `publishToMavenLocal`.

Normally a shadowJar fat jar is created via `gradle shadowjar` but the build command on JitPack is not configurable therefore we must modify our `publishToMavenLocal` to use shadowJar.

Answer (score 4):

I made a support request with JitPack and they've come back with the following code which I have tested to be working as of 2018/04/12:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "2.0.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

group = 'com.github.jitpack-io'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

shadowJar {
    archiveName = "$baseName-$version.$extension"
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
    archives shadowJar
}
```

They've published the code via [GitHub](https://github.com/jitpack-io/gradle-simple/blob/shadow/build.gradle).

It can also be combined with the gradle wrapper:

```
allprojects {
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '4.4'
        distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

probably a little to late but I got it running but just adding the artifact into the publish part like this:

```
publishing {
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId project.group
        artifactId project.name
        version project.version
        from components.java
        artifact sourceJar {
            classifier "sources"
        }
        artifact shadowJar
    }
}....
```